# How to reorganize/restructure values in a dataframe with no column header by refering to a master dataframe in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Master Dataframe:

| **B** | **D** | **E** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 | d1 | e1 |
| b2 | d2 | e2 |
| b3 | d3 |  |
|  | d4 |  |
|  | d5 |  |

Dataframe with no column name:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| b1 |  |
| d3 | e1 |
| d2 |  |
| b2 | e2 |
| e1 |  |
| d5 | e1 |

How do i convert the dataframe above to something like in the table below (with column names) by refering to master dataframe?

| **B** | **D** | **E** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b1 |  |  |
|  | d3 | e1 |
|  | d2 |  |
| b2 |  | e2 |
|  |  | e1 |
|  | d5 | e1 |

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to make a mapping dict, then reindex each row:

```
# Mapping dict
d = {}
for k, v in df.to_dict("list").items():
    d.update(**dict.fromkeys(set(v) - {np.nan}, k))

# or pandas approach
d = df.melt().dropna().set_index("value")["variable"].to_dict()

def reorganize(ser):
    data = [i for i in ser if pd.notna(i)]
    ind = [d.get(i, i) for i in data]
    return pd.Series(data, index=ind)

df2.apply(reorganize, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     B    D    E
0   b1  NaN  NaN
1  NaN   d3   e1
2  NaN   d2  NaN
3   b2  NaN   e2
4  NaN  NaN   e1
5  NaN   d5   e1
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a beautiful answer, but I think I was able to do it by using `.loc`. I don't think you need to use Master Dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['b1', 'd3', 'd2', 'b2', 'e1', 'd5'],
                   'col2': ['', 'e1', '', 'e2', '', 'e1']},
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df
#   col1 col2
# 0   b1     
# 1   d3   e1
# 2   d2     
# 3   b2   e2
# 4   e1     
# 5   d5   e1

df_reshaped = pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        i = row[col]
        j = i[0] if i != '' else ''
        if j != '':
            df_reshaped.loc[index, j] = i
            
df_reshaped.columns = df_reshaped.columns.str.upper()
df_reshaped
#      B    D    E
# 0   b1  NaN  NaN
# 1  NaN   d3   e1
# 2  NaN   d2  NaN
# 3   b2  NaN   e2
# 4  NaN  NaN   e1
# 5  NaN   d5   e1
```

Comment: Thank You for taking time time to look in to this :)

Comment: @VigneshRamasamy My code is simple and easy to understand.